# SCP stuck on file copying

Tags: ssh, rsync, scp

I have a test file with a simple text inside. 
If filesize more then 750 bytes I can not transfer it via SCP or rsync.

> Internet works fine on the host and has Download: 16.53 Mbit/s Upload: 2.83
>   Mbit/s

```
-rw-rw-r--  1  4395 Nov  4 18:34 test

 scp -v  test  deployer@vpn-test_host:/home/deployer

debug1: Sending command: scp -v -t /home/deployer
Sending file modes: C0664 4395 test
Sink: C0664 4395 test
test                                       0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA
```

Ubuntu 18.04 is installed on both sides. 
How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Please Edit the question with the OS being used on both sender and recipient.  Ubuntu 1804, Windows 10v1809 with WSL, MacOS 10.14 ?  scp is slightly different between OSes.  I'm not certain what the dot slash does in "./test" ... I would try "test" .  Also, have you tried fetching from the other machine, instead of sending?

Comment: ./ is just the current directory. Ubuntu 18.04 on both sides. I tried fetching from the other machine and it works. But don't work for sending it.

Comment: In the standard bash shell, "./test" means " execute the file test" but I'm not certain what it does inside the scp command.  Please give the command a try without the dot slash.

Comment: I have just tried without "./" there is no difference the result is the same.